# Bandwidth for audio stream for the mobile client

Tags: mp3, audio-streaming, bandwidth, aac, icecast

1/ I would like to know if I am computing (with rough precision) the bandwidth for MP3/AAC audio stream correctly. Parameters of the stream are:

```
Sample rate: 44100,  
Bitrate: 128bit
Channels: 2,
Stream type: icecast (no metadata)
Codecs used: MP3 or AAC
```

The raw audio would be: `44100*128*2 = 11289600 bits/sec = 11025 kbit/sec = ~10.8 MBit/sec`. I will count with **10:1 compression ratio** (which I think can be more or less correct - but please correct me, if I am wrong) then approx. **1 Megabit/sec** should be enough.

2/ Is the computation correct? Because this means that for GPRS (~80 kbps), EDGE (~230kbps), UMTS (~384kbps) it does not make sense to even try those streams. If my computation is correct, then the only technology would be then the HDSPA, which starts on ~1.8 Mbps.

3/ Can someone give me good parameters for the streaming for the mobile audio streaming?

Thanks a lot 
BR
STeN

Comment: Hi, the question is solved - the 'bitrate' value does not mean bits per sample but it is already a value describing the stream bandwidth per second, which means it is 128 kbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have figured out the first part of this, that the audio is actually 16 bit, and that the bitrate specified here is for the compressor.

The second part is choosing a bitrate appropriate for mobile streaming.  In my tests, I've found that you don't really want to go higher than 96kbit, but 64kbit is generally acceptable.

To get a decent audio quality at 64kbit, you can encode the stream in mono.  If you prefer stereo, you will get many compression artifacts at this bitrate.  Only AAC would be recomended at that point, which works very well at low bitrates.

At least in my area, the bandwidth just isn't there to reliably do anything higher, and this is on EvDO.

Comment: Thanks for comments!! So for lower bitrates the AAC fits better then MP3? Can you tell me the reason for this? Is it better compression algorithm? Can it be that for the lower bitrates the AMR will be used? It is for sure for the speech coding – but might it be used for the radio as well? Did you see this to be used? Do we have some other options then AAC and MP3? THANKS for the reply.

Comment: What about the OGG? Will this be an option?

Comment: You can actually run anything you want through SHOUTcast/Icecast.  All it does is relay bytes.  (Telnet into the encoder side, send the appropriate headers, and then type.  Then, telnet into the client side.  You will see what I mean!)  As far as what is supported, MP3 is king, and AAC is right behind it.  As far as which codec is better, to my ears, AAC works better than MP3 at lower bitrates.  I have not compared the two at higher bitrates, but have read that others find it to be not as good.  You should experiment to see what sounds better to you.  MP3 starts to get good above 160kbps.

Comment: Yes, you can use OGG, but I'm not sure about client support, outside of VLC/Winamp.